# distance between parametric line and a point $(4,3,s)$

Tags: calculus, 3d, parametric, vectors

I've tried solving this problem every way I know how and I just can't get it.  I've looked at similar problems of this type, and I still cannot get an answer that seems right.

Parametric Equations:

**a) Write the distance between the line and the point as a function of s**

**b) Find the value of s such that the above distance is minimum**

> $$x = -t+3$$
>
> $$y = \frac{t}{2} +1$$
>
> $$z = 2t - 1$$

Point:

> (4,3,s)

The most obvious thing seems to be to use the distance formula, but this gives a function of s and t.  I can take partials of this equation to find s and t, but for some reason this seems wrong to me.

$$D = \sqrt{(4-(-t + 3))^2  + (3 - (1/2t + 1))^2 + (s - (2t- 1))^2}$$

$$D^2 = (1 + t)^2 + (2 - 1/2t)^2 + (s - 2t -1)^2$$

$$D^2 = 19/4t^2 + 4t + s^2 - 4st - 2s + 6$$

partial w/ respect to s = 2s - 4t -2

partial w/ respect to t = 19/2t + 4 - 4s

t = 0, s = 1 ???

I've tried all sorts of other methods, including taking the cross product of the two direction vectors to find a normal vector perpendicular to both, as this is the minimum distance from a vector to a point.  At this point my head is spinning and I just don't know the right approach.  Any hints?  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

In the first part, we are taking $s$ to be some *fixed* (but unspecified) value. The distance from *a point* on the parametric line to the given point is indeed $$\sqrt{(1+t)^2+\left(2-\frac12t\right)^2+(s-2t-1)^2}.\tag{$\star$}$$ To find the distance from *the parametric line, itself* to the given point, we must minimize this. It suffices to minimize its square. To do this, we will take the partial derivative of its square with respect to $t,$ set it equal to $0,$ solve for $t$, and plug it back into $(\star),$ to give us a function in terms of $s.$

Then, to find $s$ such that the distance is at a minimum, we will square the resulting function and minimize, by taking the derivative with respect to $s,$ setting equal to $0,$ and solving for $s$.

Answer (score 0):

Line: $(x, y, z) = (3, 1, -1) + t(-1, 1/2, 2)$

Point: $(4, 3, s)$

The point must lie in a plane that is perpendicular to the line.
So the plane needs to be perpendicular to the vector $(-1, 1/2, 2)$

This would be the plane $-x + \frac 1 2 y + 2z = C.\;$
To find C, we let $(x, y, z) = (4, 3, s)$

$C = -4 + \frac 3 2 + 2s = -\frac 5 2 + 2s$

So the plane is $-x + \frac 1 2 y + 2z = 2s - \frac 5 2.\;$

This plane intersect the line when

$-(3-t) + \frac 1 2 (1 - \frac 1 2 t) + 2(s + 2) = 2s - \frac 5 2.\;$

$t = -8$.

So, the point on the line is at

$(3, 1, -1) + (-8)(-1, 1/2, 2) = (11, -3, -17)$

The distance between $(11, -3, -17)$ and $(4, 3, s)$ is 
$\sqrt{s^2+34 s+374}$